# Find the moment generating function for a given pdf by using a special type of function

Tags: statistics, moment-generating-functions

Let $X$ be a random variable with pdf $$
f(x)=\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{-x}}{\left(\mathrm{e}^{-x}+1\right)^2}$$ $-\infty< x<\infty$, I have to find the mgf of $X$.

The question gives a hint: write in an integral that is a special type of function.

So I let $$u=\mathrm{e}^{-x}$$ and then substitute it in to the function and try to make a Gamma function but didn't work out...

Comment: You need to have more detailed progress of yours.

Comment: $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-x}}{\left(\mathrm{e}^{-x}+1\right)^2}\, dx=1$ as you might hope for a density.  But an MGF requires a different integral

Comment: $$F(\alpha)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-x}e^{\alpha x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2}dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^xe^{\alpha x}}{(1+e^x)^2}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{t^\alpha}{(1+t)^2}dt$$
$$E(x^k)=\frac{d^k}{d\alpha^k}\bigg|_{\alpha=0}F(\alpha)$$